# Pulley system, what is the ratio?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

[image]

I've got this pulley system and I am not sure what the ratio is, that is if I pull the rope at S for example 10 cm how much will the block move? My guess is 10cm pull = $\frac{10}{4}$ cm at the block, a friend says it is $\frac{10}{3}$ cm. What is correct and why? I think it is $\frac{10}{4}$ cm because there are two pulleys and twice the rope on each side, while my friend say it is 3 because the rope only turn back and forward 3 times

Comment: Is it 3 because we got 2 connection points to the block and one of the connection points must hold 2s which mean 1+2=3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you moved the block a distance $AB$ as shown in the diagram but the string, which was no longer flexible, did not move.

The system would look something like this with the small pulley attached to the block having moved a distance $AB$.

[image]

How far would you have to move $S$ to have the string, which is now flexible, to be tight around the pulleys again?

Comment: Elegant visualization!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have tried to present a conventional but easy-to-understand Constraint method to deal with this problem.
Although there are many method but it is the most comprehensible approach to tackle this problem.